# It has been a while since I watched you sleep

Tags: word-choice

> It has been a while since I watched you sleep.

Is ***watched*** or ***saw*** more correct in sentence above? What is the difference in meaning between the two choices?

Comment: Don't accept an answer so quickly. Wait a while, like a day or two, for other answers to appear, and then carefully select and accept an answer.

Comment: Both versions ("watched" vs "saw") are good sentences, but they can have different meanings and would usually be used in different contexts.

Comment: Is no one going to mention that the sentence with "watched" in it has connotations of being creepy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll address 'watch' and 'see'.

**In one line -** *watch* is for moving object **or** looking at/seeing something over a period of time. Generally the result is expected. *see* is just seeing, in most of the cases, still objects and it might not be intentional.

**Explanation-**

*Watch* **generally** refers to something which is in motion and you are interested in the result. *See* simply implies looking the still subject. Also *see* comes with *no intention* and *watch* comes with intention. In other words, *seeing* is not avoidable but *watch* is intentionally done. You open up the curtain and ***see*** the birds outside. You **watch** birds drinking water (moving, result oriented).

You generally don't *see* movie on television but ***watch*** it. On the other hand you generally don't *watch* still photographs but ***see/look (at)*** them.

BBC writes:

> When we watch something, we intend to look at it but we're also looking at it quite intensely, usually because it's ***moving***. So, for example, "I watched the bus go through the traffic lights." "I watched the movie." We want to see it, we're looking at it intensely and it's ***normally moving.***
>
> Remember, 'see' – you didn't really intend to, it just happened; 'look' – you intended to do it; and watch you intended to do it and you were looking intensely, usually because ***it was moving.***

[Full article here.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/spanish/specials/1125_questions/page5.shtml)

Now it depends on the context which way *sleep* is used. Do you mean that you observed/watched the object trying to fall asleep and then finally slept? If that so, I watch might work. But still, to my ears, *watching* someone sleep does not look natural unless you do that for a period of time. Better expression to say that you are looking at a sleeping person for quite some time (as for a gatekeeper), you may say...

> I have been watching you sleeping for past half an hour

On the other hand, *saw* can be used this way...

> I saw you sleeping for half an hour

Comment: I wouldn't say use saw with something ongoing like "I saw you sleeping for half an hour." I would say "I saw you sleeping at your desk. Were you up late?" or "I watched you sleep for half an hour. It looked like you were having a bad dream."

Comment: -1, your post is wrong. A person can ***see a movie,*** if that person wants to pay an arm and a leg in order to do so. A parent can ***watch*** a sick child as the child sleeps.

Comment: I agree with FE's comments. I find it interesting that we see a film at the cinema (BrE), but watch a film on television. It's also interesting that we say "I am going to watch  'Casablanca' tonight (on TV)" but "I saw 'Casablanca' last night (on TV)". However, if we are think of the activity of sitting and peering at the screen, we might say "I watched 'Casablanca' last night (on TV)".

Comment: @F.E. watching a child is all different thing. Again, you ***watch*** the child for a period of time (of course, it'll include all motion and you are **interested** in result (as I said). Good read is [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/spanish/specials/1125_questions/page5.shtml) Watch out-it talks about *moving* objects. Editing my answer with reference anyway.

Comment: @tunny reference added. My post is *not* incorrect!

Comment: @F.E. And if you look all other answers, they talk the same. Watching - for a period of time, moving object, interested in result and seeing, still object, unavoidable.

Comment: @MaulikV I'm a native English speaker. The verbs "look" and "see" and "watch" have some overlap in meaning, and have numerous differences. The differences and nuances are going to be difficult for a foreign speaker to pick up, and it would take a long time for an EFL speaker to use them properly. For example: *You can **look** at photographs. You can see photographs lying on a table. You can pick one up and look at it carefully. You can put the photograph back on the table with the rest, and then hide behind a sofa and watch the photographs to see if someone will come by to steal them.*

Comment: @MaulikV- I think the part that is wrong is when you say "you never see a movie, you watch them" and also when you say that "watching someone sleep* doesn't sound natural.  It's completely natural and correct, but as Millie points out, in the wrong context it could sound a little creepy.

Comment: @F.E. We are discussing about *watch* and *see*. And I did not touch the verb *look* at all in my answer. Anyway, if *never* was the word that looked incorrect in my answer, I removed it.

Comment: *"On the other hand you generally don't watch still photographs but see them."* <== That is un-idiomatic. A person ***looks*** at a photograph. A person can ***see*** photographs lying on a table.

Comment: @F.E. You can certainly *see* photographs. However, *look* is not incorrect. *TMZ reports that after listening to the recording of the incident, speaking to witnesses and **seeing** photographs of Lucas and Watts in the car, state prosecutors decided to prosecute the pair for lewd conduct.* -[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2014/oct/21/daniele-watts-django-unchained-actor-charged-lewd-conduct)

Comment: Yes, the prosecutors **saw** that there were photographs of Lucas and Watts in the car. The prosecutors had most likely **looked** carefully at those photographs. And the prosecutors **saw** that the  photographs would be good evidence for them in that case. When a person is actually looking at a photograph, where the person is studying the details in that photograph, then, that person is **looking** at the photograph--you would not say that the person was **seeing** the photograph.

Comment: @F.E. That was just one of the examples. I have many that simply says 'see photographs' means 'see photographs' but I won't get further into it. I edited my answer though because if a *native* like you thinks it's incorrect, it should be corrected! :)

Comment: *"You generally don't see movie or television but watch them."* <== Actually, both "see" and "watch" is used. For example: *A:"Did you **see** that movie last night?" B: "Yes, I **watched** it with my girlfriend."*

Comment: @MaulikV - Regardless of what the BBC say, a private detective can watch a house for hours.

Comment: @tunny Exactly. In fact, it is **in regard to BBC** (You watched it (intentionally)) and **my answer** (the result was expected!)

Answer (score 6):

"Saw" can indicate a momentary observation while "watch" indicates prolonged viewing, as others have said. But beyond that, "watch" indicates a deliberate action, an intent to observe, while "see" does not. You can "see" something accidentally. You can not "watch" something accidentally.

Like, "I was walking past Sally's house and I looked at the window and SAW her undress." The view is accidental. The speaker may be as embarrassed about the incident as the subject. Versus, "I was walking past Sally's house and I looked at the window and WATCHED her undress." The view is deliberate. He stood there and watched. The speaker is a peeping Tom.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but they have different meanings. *Watched* implies a longer time period - you pulled up a chair and spent an extended period of time watching the subject sleep. *Saw* implies a shorter time. You walked past the bedroom door and briefly saw the subject asleep.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between "[watch](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/watch?s=t)" and "[see](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/see?s=t)" in general is the attentiveness of the observer, not the duration of the observation or the activity that's being observed.

> I watched you sleep, and saw you change position 16 times in half an hour.
> I watched the quick motion of the magician's hands, but didn't see how the trick was done.
> There are stories that the painting is haunted, so I watched it carefully to see if it changed.

If you mean *"I haven't noticed you sleeping - are you getting enough rest?"*

> It has been a while since I've seen you sleep.

If you want to say, *"I sometimes observe you while you're sleeping, and it's been a while since I've done that."* you would say:

> It has been a while since I've watched you sleep. Our sleep study experiment is going to have gaps in the data.